# body tag margin creating bad whitespace up top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't get rid of the white margin on the body tag at the top of my page. I will add the necessary .body formatting but it is still there and my inspector still shows the default 8px padding for some reason. Why would the body not be picking this up?

```
@import "bootstrap";
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Open+Sans+Condensed:300);


.body {
    margin:0px;
}

.container-top {
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    background-color: #424b51;
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should remove the dot '.' from body.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove dot from before body.

```
body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```